# How to in linux sh insert argv argument?

Tags: linux, sh

I programming a small installation program in sh, and I do not know how then argv argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

`#!/bin/sh`

`Dosomething $1 $2`

Answer (score 1):

In bash, command line arguments are retrieved in $1, $2, $3, ... variables. This is true both for scripts and for functions inside scripts.

```
man bash
```

is worth a read.

Comment: Bash and sh are different shells. Some Linux distribution use Bash also for sh, but this is not the case on other OSes like the BSD family.

Comment: That's true, but for argv handling there is no difference between sh and bash.